# If one media query dont have CSS formatting, html content catches another media query?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to do my first project with media queries, and I'm facing a strange issue.

I started to develop for mobile, using this media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width:479px)  {}
```

Then, I develop for larger mobile devices with:

```
@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:600px) {}
```

Then for small tablets:

```
@media screen and (min-width:601px) and (max-width:720px) {}
```

And larger tablets:

```
@media screen and (min-width:721px) and (max-width:980px)
```

Then for laptop:

```
@media screen and (min-width:981px) {}
```

Everything works fine so far, but now I'm doing this media query `@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {}` for larger laptops, and when I resize the browser up to 1200, and If I don't have nothing inside this media query, my content rather than stay unformatted, what happens is that my content catches the previous media query: `@media screen and (min-width:981px) {}`.

Is this is normal?? If one media query doesn't have CSS formatting, the content catches another media query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is nothing inside a media query, then the browser doesn't need to change anything.

Since anything that is at least 1200px (`min-width:1200px`) is necessarily also at least 981px (`min-width:981px`), anything that applies in the latter will apply in the former if nothing is changed. In a way, you *could* say that the browser "catches" the earlier media query, but it really is catching *both*; there is just nothing in the second to override the first so the styles remain the same.

This is expected behavior.

The reason why your mobile and tablet media queries *don't* apply on laptops (and desktops) is because you have specified `max-width`, unlike your laptop media query, which only has a `min-width` condition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, very clear explanation and now I get it :)